# How to set icon name in X11 (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, x11

I have written an application in C++, using an in-house toolkit (no Gnome or KDE). When I run it on Ubuntu (18.04), and press alt-tab, I can see the icon I have set for the application, but there is no icon name underneath the icon. See attached image: the terminal has a terminal icon and the word "Terminal" underneath, but my own application only has the word "Unknown".

[image]

Presumably I need to set one of the many possible X11 window properties, but I don't know which one. xprops, when used with the terminal window, doesn't reveal any properties that have value "Terminal". I've tried setting property _NET_WM_ICON_NAME (a likely choice) to a name of my choice, but it doesn't help.

How can I change the word "Unknown" to something of my choice? Again - this application is using an in-house toolkit, which is neither Gnome nor KDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. Using XSetClassHint solves the problem:

```
    XClassHint *class_hint = XAllocClassHint();
    
    if (class_hint)
    {
        class_hint->res_name = class_hint->res_class = (char *)application_name
        XSetClassHint(display, window, class_hint);
        XFree(class_hint);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had given up hope on this after so much time, but you came through for me :-) Note that the current window manager shows the window title in the alt-tab box, so that already worked better, but the "unknown" was still present if you hovered the mouse over the icon in the task bar. Setting the class hint fixes that. Great work!

Answer (score 2):

There is a function for that: XSetWMName. It takes an XTextProperty as argument:

```
void VTXWidget::setName (const std::string &name)
{
  XTextProperty tp;
  char *props[1];

  props[0] = strdup (name.c_str ());
  if (0 == props[0])
  {
    return;
  }

  if (!XStringListToTextProperty (props, 1, &tp))
  {
    TR_ERR ("Failed to convert text property");
  }
  else
  {
    XSetWMName (m_display, m_window, &tp);
    XFree (tp.value);
  }

  free (props[0]);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I'm afraid that's not correct. This sets WM_NAME, which is the window title, but that's a different string from the one used for the icon displayed when you press ALT-TAB. Sorry :-)

Comment: Odd. Why would the name of your window (e.g. "Firefox") be different from the icon name when alt-tabbing?

Comment: That's an excellent question, but sadly not one I know the answer to... If I were to guess, maybe because the icon has different layout constraints? The window has a lot of space available for the title, but the icons are presented in a row, with not too much space available for each name. There are properties that are suggestive of this, such as _NET_WM_ICON_NAME, but that doesn't do anything meaningful for me either.

Comment: I think _NET_WM_ICON_NAME is used for minimized windows.